# How can I setup 2 Cloud Firestore Projects to Link to One Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I setup 2 Cloud Firestore Projects to Link to One Flutter App and work at the same time?

There is no documentation on the Firebase website for how to attach 2 Firebase databases directly to a Flutter app so that when the app is on the app store, the app can communicate to the 2 databases. I don't for example want 2 environments like production and debug, and then to compile for one of these when the time comes to upload - I want the app to communicate with the 2 databases in production.

Creating another firebase.options file is fine - but then comes the issue of having 2 GoogleService-Info.plist files and 2 google-services.json files.

How can I use the Firebase CLI to differentiate and locate these when configuring the second database?

Comment: You have to initialize a new firebase app object with the information about the second project and use that to communicate with the database in that project.

Comment: @DougStevenson I understand that part - it's more about dealing with the 2 GoogleServe-Info.plist files and google-services.json files - as I'm creating 2 instances theres going to be 2 versions - so how do I allow for this? The Firebase CLI only allows overwriting of the first database GoogleServe-Info.plist and google-services.json files. There is nothing in the documentation about dealing with these files when using Flutter.

Comment: I don't think you can have two of those config files.  You can initialize a new firebase app instance without the config file by passing in all the required data in code.  See the API docs for that.

Comment: This was correct - I have updated the question above!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doug's answer was correct. **The process to address this is as follows:**

1. Write the following your project directory terminal:

   flutterfire configure -p yourSecondDatabaseName -o lib/yourNewFirebaseOptionsFile.dart

This will create a second firebase_options file (here it's named yourNewFirebaseOptionsFile, but it can be anything.

2. Select your required platforms (in my case it was iOS and Android).
3. Firebase CLI should then ask regarding overwriting Firebase AppID Files/GoogleService-Info.plist files/google-services.json files. Put NO for all of these - we don't want to erase the original files from our first project.
4. In my case, I encountered unhandled exceptions to putting NO in these fields. It said "Firebase App ID file is already up to date".
5. Your app and their respective platforms should be registered under Project Settings, General.
6. Use the following setup to initialise a second Firebase instance in your main() and link to your second database:

```
         if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          //Android app ID's from firebase console of project 2
            name: 'secondDatabase',
            options: const FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey: '',
              appId: '',
              messagingSenderId: '',
              projectId: '',
              storageBucket: '',
            ));
  

    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
        await Firebase.initializeApp(
          //iOS app ID's from firebase console of project 2
            name: 'secondDatabase',
            options: const FirebaseOptions(
              apiKey: '',
              appId: '',
              messagingSenderId: '',
              projectId: '',
              storageBucket: '',
            ));
      }
```

You can find the values of these fields inside the new firebase options file you generated for the second database.

7. Final step: Instantiate a new FirebaseFirestore object to now read/write as you require from the second database:

```
FirebaseFirestore _firestore2 = FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app('secondDatabase'))
```